# Looping through values in a specific column and changing values Python and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, loops, replace

I have a dataframe as follows (example is simplified):

```
id       prediction1          prediction2
1234     Cocker_spaniel       german_Shepard
5678     rhodesian_ridgeback  australian_shepard
```

I need to remove the underscores and make sure the string is in lower case so I can search it easier later.

I am not quite sure how to loop through this. My initial student thought is something like what follows:

```
for row in image_predictions['p1']:
    image_predictions['p1'] = image_predictions['p1'].replace('_', ' ')
```

The above code is for replacing the underscore with a space and I believe the code would be similar for lowercase using the .lower() method.

Any advice to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5):

For in place modification you can use:

```
df.update(df[['prediction1', 'prediction2']]
          .apply(lambda c: c.str.lower()
                            .str.replace('_', ' ', regex=False))
          )
```

Output:

```
     id          prediction1         prediction2
0  1234       cocker spaniel      german shepard
1  5678  rhodesian ridgeback  australian shepard
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you! Would you mind educating a student as to what the 'c' is for? I am familiar with lambda form, but I don't seem to know why you are using 'c' in that manner/

Comment: It's just a variable name you can use anything. I used `c` for column. Sometimes I use `x` ;)

Comment: Note that this vectorized approach should be fast but if you were to use more than 2/3 `str` methods, it might be worth considering using a non vectorized method (and compare the timings), it might be faster.

Comment: @Wildo_Baggins311 if you do some timings, I'm curious if the approach I put is really slow because it uses replace in regex=True mode

Comment: @mitoRibo I didn't set it (and the default value if changing soon to False), but it should be False in this case. Note that I used `str.replace`, not `replace` ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `image_predictions['p1'].apply()` to apply a function to each cell of the p1 column:

```
def myFunction(x):
    return x.replace('_', ' ')
image_predictions['p1'] = image_predictions['p1'].apply(myFunction)
```

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to see if it was possible to not have to specify the columns for replacement. This approach creates a dict to replace A -> a, B -> b, etc, and _ -> space. Then uses `replace` with `regex=True`

```
import string

replace_dict = dict(zip(string.ascii_uppercase,string.ascii_lowercase))
replace_dict['_'] = ' '

df.replace(replace_dict, regex=True, inplace=True)

print(df)
```